# MULTIPLE QUERY_STRING COMBINED ALONE QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've a list of redirections to do and many of them are similar to others, but less or more restrictives, for example:

http://www.example.com/example/form.aspx?code=2
to 
http://www.google.com

And in the other hand:

http://www.example.com/form.aspx?category=5&code=2
to
http://www.microsoft.com

Now i tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=2$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/example/form(.*)"
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/example/form(.*)"
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.microsoft.com? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that any of that goes to http://www.google.com/?code=2 or http://www.google.com/?code=2&category=5

Have you any suggestions?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case for

> http://www.example.com/example/form.aspx?code=2 --> http://www.google.com
>
> http://www.example.com/form.aspx?category=5&code=2 --> http://www.microsoft.com

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=2$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=2$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.microsoft.com? [R=301,L]
```

In case for

> http://www.example.com/example/form.aspx?category=5&code=2 --> http://www.microsoft.com
>
> http://www.example.com/example/form.aspx?category=5&code=234 --> http://www.stackoverflow.com

Use this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=2$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.microsoft.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=234$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rules to redirect your urls :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /example/form\.aspx\?code=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /example/form\.aspx\?category=5&code=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://microsoft.com/? [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

And any other question:

if you have more than one with 1 element like, and the other is similar to the previous, is any way to specify without need to sort?

Now if i have for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} **code=2**
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.microsoft.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} **code=234**
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/form(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.stackoverflow.com? [R=301,L]
```

It goes allways to the http://www.microsoft.com because  code=234 contains code=2....

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=2$` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} code=234$` instead of `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} **code=2**` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} **code=234**` respectively.

Comment: Next time please update it to your question or ask a new question instead of adding as another answer.